# you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
import random

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class TweetLike(models.Model):
    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    tweet = models.ForeignKey("Tweet", on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)

class Tweet(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey("", null = True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name="tweets") 
    likes = models.IntegerField(default= 0 )
    content = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank = True, null = True)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='images/', blank = True, null = True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add= True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
    def serialize(self):
        return{
            "id": self.id,
            "content": self.content,
            "likes": random.randint(0,200)
        }
```

While Migrating my models i get the error

Comment: What error do you get when migrating? Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64011839/edit) your question with more information.

Comment: valueError: Cannot alter field tweets.Tweet.likes into tweets.Tweet.likes - they are not compatible types (you cannot alter to or from M2M fields, or add or remove through= on M2M fields)

Comment: Great. Please [update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64011839/edit) your question with the exception.